# Move remote files to a remote directory

Tags: ftp

With only ftp commands, how to move all files in a directory to another directory?

I don't know the names of the files, only the directory where they are. For example I want to move all files in `base_dir`

```
base_dir/file1
base_dir/file2
base_dir/destination_dir/
```

to a directory inside `base_dir`:

```
base_dir/destination_dir/file1
base_dir/destination_dir/file2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
RNFR base_dir
RNTO base_dir_temp

MKD base_dir

RNFR base_dir_temp
RNTO base_dir/destination_dir
```